# Creating an oracle view with cast is giving an error in oracle sql developer

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using the following query to create an oracle view in oracle sql developer,

```
    select * from (SELECT DATEENTER as PI_TIMESTAMP,PI_TAG as  PI_TAGNAME, 
case when LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(final, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) is null then cast(final as number) else null end as PI_VALUE,
STATUS AS  PI_STATUS  
FROM T2) a
where PI_VALUE is not null
```

The query is working fine in a query window, however it is giving me the error **Error(s) parsing SQL: Unexpected token at 134 near ). Unexpected token at 136 near is.**   when i try to create it as a view

Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the query. Does it work when you run it from SQL*Plus?

Comment: yes it works fine, only when trying to create a view out of it the error pops up

Comment: If you get an error when trying to create your view from SQL*Plus, then please post your complete statement. I was able to create a view using your above statement just fine.

Comment: I am using the same statement to create the view, since it worked fine with u then I am begining to suspect that my sql developer is corrupted, really wierd

Answer (score 3):

Probably, SQL Developer is getting confused by the column name "final". "final" is used in Oracle PL/SQL to prevent inheriting from an Object type.

Try running your statement in SQL/Plus - should work fine.

BTW, I'd recommend using to_number(final) instead of a plain cast.

Comment: Thanks, but actually the column final is a string,

Comment: Of course, but you are still telling Oracle to "treat final as a number" without specifying any number format. If you use to_number(), you can provide a number format - this will allow you to handle NLS-specific issues etc. correctly. FYI: You also don't handle scientific numbers ('1E2') in your translate() correctly.

Comment: Thanks Frank for pointing this out, Actually my point of this translation was to use the SQL funtion IsNumeric in oracle, so that's the only thing i found, can it be better than this? thanks again